# Sending data with JavaScript to MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am looking for a simple way to send data from client to server database. I exept a simple piece of code in java that sends data from client to server in any way.

For example in this code I want to store in my database how many times the button was pressed by some user(with some id, we use id to find a row in database and increment value in second column).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
      function count(form){
        form.games.value=eval(form.num.value)+1;
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <?php
      $con=new mysqli(mysql_host,mysql_user,mysql_password,mysql_database);
      $sql="select * from Users where ID='".$_POST['id']."'";
      $result=$con->query($sql);
      $arr=$result->fetch_row();
      $val=$arr[1];
      echo "
        <form name=\"display\">
        <textarea class=message readonly=true disabled=true name=\"num\">{$val}</textarea>
        <input type=button value=\"Hit\" onClick=\"count(this.form)\">
      ";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope my question is not too broad this time.

Comment: Google: AJAX. jQuery makes it easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's called Javascript (one word), to make your questions more clear in the future. You could use jQuery's [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function to send an HTTP GET request to a PHP page that would record the data onto the database. You can send along with it the data such as ID as the example on the jQuery page.

Basic flow:

1. User Clicks Button
2. jQuery Sends Get request to PHP
3. PHP Page Executes mysql command to record click
4. PHP returns successful (you can use a [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode) for the return) or failure.
5. Your Javascript tells the user that the command was sent successfully.